# How to handle TypeError: place.address_components[2] in google autocomplete map search?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am developing a google map app with autocomplete option.  I am using `place.address_components[2].short_name` to fetch state. It works fine for some city but not for all. Like for arizona it gives `TypeError: place.address_components[2] is undefined` 
How to handle this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (typeof  place.address_components[2] != 'undefined') {
             var state = place.address_components[2].short_name.toLowerCase();
    } else {
            // do something else;
    }
```

Above code solves my problem. Thanks @Spencer Lockhart for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

check if it's defined:

```
if (place.address_components[2] !== undefined) { // if this is true, it is defined.

}
```

Or you can use try/catch if you feel it's necessary.. Try to avoid try/catch if you can.

I'm not sure what it means to google maps if address_components[2] is undefined, you should try logging address_components to see what it is for the address in Arizona VS other results.

There must be a way to get the state.. Play around with your data.

Comment: I tried that. But it also gives the same error at the same line where  I wrote if (address_components[2] !== undefined) {

Comment: I meant place.address_components[2], my bad.

Comment: I actually don't realize your typo :P. I also tried place.address_components[2]

Comment: how can it be undefined if you are checking it before referencing it? There must be some misunderstanding. is 'place' actually undefined? you need to place all references to address_components[2] in a place where it won't get used unless it is defined, then JS won't yell if it's undefined.

Comment: I am also not sure why this is happening. But it's giving error on the line I tries to check if it is undefined or not.